# Saref core based ontology and multiple measurements

Tags: ontology, protege

I have multiple devices that can provide me with multiple instances. How do I take into consideration this cardinality when designing a saref ontology? I'm using protege.

Comment: You can see examples of how to specify this on my [blog](https://henrietteharmse.com/2017/11/03/associations-between-classes/).

Comment: Interesting post. But does that mean I can have multiple measurements by adding a min range for the measurement on the device class? Does the saref ontology allow that?

Comment: Please provide your minimal complete example ontology with a clear indication of what it is that is not working as you expected it to work.

Comment: I'm using this saref as a base for my ontology https://saref.etsi.org/core/v3.1.1/
In my case, I have a device that can generate multiple readings aka measurements. Looking at this ontology I don't think the device can support multiple measurements, but I might be wrong. Thanks for your help.